# Make log of every visit to my website

Tags: html

I just finished a test website and I uploaded it in my Linux machine. I was wondering if there's a method to make Linux do a specific command when someone opens my website. My target are logs: I want Linux send me logs whenever someone opens my website. Is there a way?
P.S. Sorry for my bad english, I'm italian.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting

Comment: Yes there are several ways. Which ones have you researched and which ones have you tried implementing already and which ones caused which specific problems at exactly which step?

Answer (score 0):

You have a very open question which the answer to can definitely be found in a simple google query. But yes this is called server side scripting look into [php](https://www.w3schools.com/php/).

edit:

suggested search query:

> how to create log files with php

Answer (score 0):

The simple way. Use a server side language like PHP.

1- Create a Php file for example "logger.php".
2- Put the following code in "logger.php"

```
<?php
  # My Logger code. bla bla bla
  exec("/path/to/mylogger.sh");
?>
```

3- In your Html file add following line:

```
require("logger.php");
# or
include("logger.php");
```